# SQL - Syntax for data within X number of days pulls all data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query I need to run regularly which pulls errors from a log table for x number of days.  I originally found the syntax for the x number of days on here highlighted below with --<<.

The script pulls the information I want, throws no errors, but it pulls items from all dates not just past X days I am looking for.  No matter what value I place before `...,getdate())` it pulls all the records.

Any Ideas how to get it to correctly give me the date range from today that I am looking for?

```
SELECT 
    t2.[campaignshortname], 
    t1.[CampaignId],
    t1.[CreatedDtTm],
    t1.[Msg],
    t1.[ReferenceDate]
FROM 
    [alchemy].[CM].[CampaignLog] AS t1  (nolock)
INNER JOIN
    [alchemy].[CM].[Campaign] AS t2 ON t1.CampaignId = t2.Id
WHERE
    CAST(t1.[ReferenceDate] AS DATE) <= dateadd(DAY, -30, getdate()) --<<
    AND t1.Msg LIKE '%fail%' OR t1.Msg LIKE '%error%'
ORDER BY  
    ReferenceDate DESC
```

Comment: `and (t1.Msg like '%fail%' or t1.Msg like '%error%')`

Comment: That did the trick, thanks much.  I also had to reverse my < to >.

Comment: The evaluation order is `NOT`-> `AND` -> `OR`, but whenever you mix you should always uses parentheses to make it more readable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would actually change the query a little bit more and use between:

```
where convert(datetime, t1.[ReferenceDate]) between getdate()-30 and getdate()
and (t1.Msg like '%fail%' or t1.Msg like '%error%')
```

Although those to likes will cause a full scan of either index or table unless you subquery it.

Comment: Very helpful suggestion. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose your `t1.Msg like '%fail%' or t1.Msg like '%error%'` in parentheses, as `and` precedes `or` in execution order. As is, your condition searches in your table first rows where the date is 30 days or more before current date and message contains the word "fail", and then it searches in your table the rows where the message contains the word "error". Your condition then should be:

```
where CAST(t1.[ReferenceDate] AS DATE) <= dateadd(DAY, -30,getdate())
and (t1.Msg like '%fail%' or t1.Msg like '%error%')
```